# Simultaneous Cosmos document creation

Tags: java, concurrency, azure-cosmosdb, etag

I am getting a race condition when trying to update (here creating the document for the first time) to Cosmos with the same primary key and part key simultaneously, and as a result, I am losing one of the updates.
The business logic is to update the document if it already exists and create it if it does not exist, but losing some data if two creations occur at the same timestamp. I know we can achieve concurrency using eTag, but here the issue happens only for the first update or creation of a document.

For example, consider the following models:
`{ "id": 1, "pkey": 2, "value": ["first text"]}`   
and

`{ "id": 1, "pkey": 2, "value": ["second text"]}`   
I have some internal business logic to update and append the value array.
`{ "id": 1, "pkey": 2, "value": ["first text," "second text,"] }`   
But I lose one value when cosmos creation occurs simultaneously.
Please feel free to correct the question if any errors are found.

Please help if anyone has faced a similar issue. tried keeping etag in the request option, but the issue still persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description it looks like you are executing concurrent Replaces over existing documents.

The best way to avoid the scenario where a second concurrent Replace removed the data added by the first is to use [Optimistic Concurrency](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/database-transactions-optimistic-concurrency#optimistic-concurrency-control).

In a nutshell:

1. Read the document you want to update.
2. From the response, you obtain the ETag.
3. Apply modification locally and send the Replace operation with the IfMatchETag option.
4. If there was a concurrent Replace operation, you will get an HTTP 412 response.
5. Repeat 1-4 until you get a success response.

Full example from the Java SDK (assuing Java because your question is tagged so) repo: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-java-sql-api-samples/blob/0ead4ca33dac72c223285e1db866c9dc06f5fb47/src/main/java/com/azure/cosmos/examples/documentcrud/async/DocumentCRUDQuickstartAsync.java#L405

Comment: I also have the exact implementation and is functional when we do the concurrent replacement over an existing document. But the issue is when there is a simultaneous write and there is no existing document.

Comment: Can you explain what is a "write"? Is it a Create or Upsert?

Comment: It's an upsert.

Comment: Upsert by definition is create or replace. You mentioned you are "keeping etag in the request option", where are you getting the ETag from before the Upsert?

Comment: We are reading it from the cosmos, the issue is when the system tries to do two cosmos write (create) simultaneously with the same primary and part key.

Comment: But if you are reading it, then the document exists, instead of an Upsert, do a Replace with the 412 flow? If you are not reading it (no Etag), do a create? A create cannot have an ETag because the document does not exist, if you have 2 concurrent Creates then 1 will fail with a HTTP 409.